# Ошибки в LogCat (android studio 2.1.2)

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

Как исправить сиутацию?

```
07-25 12:33:21.481 27135-27135/ru.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources
07-25 12:33:21.485 27135-27135/ru.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.pruneResourceCache
07-25 12:33:21.513 27135-27135/ru.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method ru.myproject.SplashScreen.access$super
07-25 12:33:21.513 27135-27135/ru.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method ru.myproject.SplashScreen.access$super
07-25 12:33:21.513 27135-27135/ru.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method ru.myproject.SplashScreen.access$super
07-25 12:33:21.513 27135-27135/ru.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method ru.myproject.SplashScreen.access$super
07-25 12:33:21.513 27135-27135/ru.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method ru.myproject.SplashScreen.access$super
07-25 12:33:21.517 27135-27135/ru.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method ru.myproject.SplashScreen.access$super
07-25 12:33:21.517 27135-27135/ru.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method ru.myproject.SplashScreen.access$super
07-25 12:33:21.521 27135-27135/ru.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method ru.myproject.SplashScreen.access$super
07-25 12:33:21.521 27135-27135/ru.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method ru.myproject.SplashScreen.access$super
07-25 12:33:21.529 27135-27135/ru.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method ru.myproject.SplashScreen.access$super
07-25 12:33:21.533 27135-27135/ru.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.TransitionManager', referenced from method ru.myproject.SplashScreen.access$super
07-25 12:33:21.537 27135-27135/ru.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method ru.myproject.SplashScreen.access$super
07-25 12:33:21.537 27135-27135/ru.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method ru.myproject.SplashScreen.access$super
07-25 12:33:21.537 27135-27135/ru.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method ru.myproject.SplashScreen.access$super
07-25 12:33:21.541 27135-27135/ru.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method ru.myproject.SplashScreen.access$super
07-25 12:33:21.549 27135-27135/ru.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method ru.myproject.SplashScreen.access$super
07-25 12:33:21.549 27135-27135/ru.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method ru.myproject.SplashScreen.access$super
07-25 12:33:21.553 27135-27135/ru.myproject E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method ru.myproject.SplashScreen.access$super
```

Градл:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ru.myproject"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.+'
}
```